# Is it possible to force at least 2 IP packets when a remote computer requests a url from my linux server?

Tags: linux, networking, tcp

I have this problem.
I have advertisers sending me a postback (a url GET call to my server with certain parameters), for example http://www.example.org/pb/advertier/?param1=xxxxparam2=yyyy
The problem is that the only way that advetisers grants security (so I know that the postback comes really from them) is IP based, so I know the IP addresses of their servers and that's it, if the incoming postback comes from one of those IP, it is genuine.
The problem is that I think there are hackers out there that know how to fake the originanting IP address and just send a request to my server with fake origin IP and my application takes that request as valid.

One solution I though is that it would be cool to "force" somehow, at the tcp stack level, or similar (Im not expert at this), at least 2 packets that need to come from the hacker computer, so a TCP/IP dialog needs to happen, something like the hacker sends me some data, then my server replies back and then the hacker computer needs to sends more data (packets) in order for the GET request to be completed. This way the hacker will not be able to send his request because the reply from my server will go somewhere else (to the faked originating IP).

I hope the idea is clear, any help greatly appreciated,

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're hinting at this beeing a HTTP request, which is performed over TCP, the problem you describe doesn't really exist. Setting up a TCP connection already involves 3 packets, and the handshake would not complete if someone faked the source address.

Comment: So, I understand that it is possible to fake source/origin ip, but according to what you say it has no point, because of the tcp handshake ?
Also, is it possible, maybe, to perform the tcp handshake using the real ip and then send the data (just a one way, no return expected packet) with a faked origin ip ?

Comment: Although I'm not expert in transport layer. But I guess its hard that way. TCP is connection oriented. When you send a packet to the server, it will send you `Ack` back. If you don't get `Ack` back, it assumes congestion and after few `Ack` losses it might stop sending.

Comment: @HernanM. Yes it's possible to fake the origin IP. Most responsible ISPs will filter that away, so if you try to do that, your ISP will likely drop the outgoing packet so it doesn't reach the destination, but there's enough that don't filter out that, so it's it's a real problem, but mostly for UDP traffic. The TCP handshake establishes a connection between source ip, source port, destination ip and destination port, so it is not possible to complete the handshake but have a faked(different) source ip for the data.